# How to split a string containing date and words?

Tags: java

I have a bunch of string in the format "02-01-2014 10:02:01:001 abcd efgh"
If I want to split it as ["02-01-2014 10:02:01:001", "abcd efgh"], how do I do that?

Currently, I'm splitting based on the knowledge that the first 23 characters contain the date so I'm just taking a substring till there. Is there any better way?

Comment: If *all* the strings you have to process have the same format, substring is good. Always keep things simple.

Comment: I'd prefer to split it on the second space character because it would be easier to understand your code than splitting after 23 characters. If you can GUARENTEE the format will not change then this is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
Patter.compile("\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}\\s\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{3}\\s(.*)");
```

Then use matcher capturing group 1.